# How to resolve mcrypt error ' Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in php laravel framework?

Tags: php, mcrypt

By running 'php artisan serve' on my phpstorm, i get this error '`ErrorException` in `EncryptionServiceProvider.php` line 16:
Use of undefined constant `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` - assumed '`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`'' on browser.

I've tried reinstalling mcrypt but it didn't work. Also i didn't find any solution to this problem.

```
php artisan serve
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Users/optergy/safetybeat-dashboard-live/dashboard/config/app.php on line 83
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
```

This error is blocking me to run the project properly.

Comment: How is this related to the Swift programming language?

Comment: Mcrypt is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling mcrypt did you enable it?  It does not come enabled by default.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or restart nginx if using that.