# Undefined constant "MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128" in codeIgniter PHP 8.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, upgrade

I am upgrading php 7.x to 8.0 in CodeIgniter in local wamp server in windows 10. I found this error :-

> Message: Undefined constant "MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128"

My code is like this:-

```
$password = trim(openssl_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0..\32");
```

Error display like this:-
[image]

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126215/how-to-resolve-mcrypt-error-use-of-undefined-constant-mcrypt-rijndael-128-in

Comment: Its not working so I put new question here.. @NicoHaase

Comment: What is "it"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I put extension=extname AND extension=php_extname.dll in php.ini and restart wamp. I download libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz but I dont know how to apply it.

Comment: Did you try to look this up using any search engine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522384/how-to-install-mcrypt-extension-in-xampp shows hints about how to install MCrypt for WAMPP

Comment: My php version is 8.0. And this version is not displayed in https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240165/discussion-between-chirag-p-and-nico-haase).

Comment: Why not install v1.0.4, which is the most recent version of that extension, from https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.4/windows? PHP 8 has been released at the end of 2020, v1.0.3 of that extension is more than a year older, and it's pretty obvious that it cannot be compatible with PHP 8

Answer (score 1):

From php.net:

> This extension has been moved to the » PECL repository and is no longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 7.2.0

You can try install mcrypt extension via pecl. In my case it's Ubuntu:

```
pecl install mcrypt
```

[For windows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)

Comment: I have Wamp server in my local pc with windows 10 @Dmitry. I tried your steps but not working. I put extension=extname AND extension=php_extname.dll in php.ini and restart wamp. Nothing happen !

Comment: @chiragp also you can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590607/download-and-install-the-php-mcrypt-extension-under-windows-10